# How can i draw to canvas with C# in my xaml project?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I currently have below code:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.Fill = new RadialGradientBrush(Colors.White, Colors.Transparent)
{
    GradientOrigin = new Point(.5, .5),
    Center = new Point(.5, .5),
    RadiusX = 1.5,
    RadiusY = 1.5
};

PathGeometry geo = new PathGeometry();

PathFigure figure = new PathFigure();
figure.IsClosed = true;
figure.StartPoint = new Point(10, 10);

figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment()
{
    Point = new Point(20, 20)
});

figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment()
{
    Point = new Point(30, 10)
});

geo.Figures.Add(figure);
path.Data = geo;

Canvas.Children.Add(path);
```

But what is wrong with it? Nothing turns up. I'm expecting a black triangle with a white center gradient brush to its size limits.

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
path.Fill = new RadialGradientBrush(Colors.Black, Colors.Transparent)
{
    GradientOrigin = new Point(.5, .5),
    Center = new Point(.5, .5),
    RadiusX = 1.5,
    RadiusY = 1.5
};
```

One more point: Your code works fine. The problem must be with your last line. Is `Canvas` the name of your canvas? `Canvas` is type but here you are using it as a variable.

Comment: Ill try to rename it to MyCanvas, since it is my canvas :D

Comment: @Jason94 ok. Change your `RadialGradientBrush` too. It's a white triangle that disappears and edges

Comment: I changed it to red and blue colors, should show something? Do i need to update the canvas or invalidate it or something?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `Stroke` for the path, otherwise the triangle won't have any black part:

`path.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);`